# Mosquitto publish on Artik Cloud does not connect

Tags: cloud, mqtt, publishing, mosquitto, artik

```
mosquitto_pub -h 52.79.140.155 -p 8883 -u device_id -P device_token -t "/v1.1/messages/<device_id>" -m "{x:24}" -d
```

I am trying to run this command on Ubuntu PC to send data to ARTIK cloud.
I'm getting an error which says:

```
Client mosqpub/28288 --- sending connect
Error : The connection was lost.
```

PS - 52.79.140.155 - Ip address of api.artik.cloud

x --- Data to send on ARTIK cloud device

Comment: Port 8883 is traditionally for MQTT with SSL/TLS. Is this supposed to be a secure connection?

Comment: Yes it is an secure connection. I tried putting "--insecure" to the command but it still shows same error.

Comment: If you want to publish to your Artik Cloud, use this lab http://mqttlab.iotsim.io/artik/

Answer (score 1):

`--insecure` only removes the check that the hostname matches the CN in the certificate, it does not enable SSL/TLS

As mentioned in the man page for mosquitto_pub you must supply either `--cafile` or `--capath` pointing to the location of the CA certificate for the broker to enable MQTT over SSL/TLS.

If the broker cert is signed by a recognised public CA then you can point `--capath` at the standard CA path `/etc/ssl/certs/`

Answer (score 0):

I also observed this while it seems to work with MQTT.fx

```
openssl s_client -connect $host:$port

mosquitto_pub \
    -d \
    -h ${host} \
    -u $username -P $password -p $port \
    --capath /etc/ssl/cert \
    --insecure \
    -t $topic \
    -m "$message"
#
Client mosqpub|32310-host sending CONNECT
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

More hints:

https://developer.artik.cloud/documentation/data-management/mqtt.html